# Scroll vertical-rl div from right to left using mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I have made a `vertical-rl` enviroment;

```js
(function() {
  function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= (delta * 50);
    document.body.scrollLeft -= (delta * 50);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
  } else {
    window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
  }
})();
```

```css
#body {
  height: 80%;
  min-width: 100%;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  font-size: 3.0rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
  <p>10</p>
  <p>11</p>
  <p>12</p>
  <p>13</p>
  <p>14</p>
  <p>15</p>
  <p>16</p>
  <p>17</p>
  <p>18</p>
  <p>19</p>
  <p>20</p>
  <p>21</p>
  <p>22</p>
</div>
```

The javascript enables the vertical body to scroll from left to right by scrolling down with the mouse scroller.

But since this is a vertical-**rl** enviroment, how can I edit the script to scroll to the other direction; **from right to left**? I've done my best to edit the script but cannot quite figure out how.

**Edit: try opening the snippet on full page.**

Comment: You may find that though the attribute is vertical-rl only the content will run right-to-left; the overflow still runs left-to-right. This is an issue to do with how your overflow is laid out.

Comment: @D-Waqas Thanks, your comment inspired me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the html body itself is `dir="rtl"`, the scrolling shall work the opposite direction. Therefore, set the body as `dir="rtl"` and make a div which is `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` and `dir="ltr`. And change the script's two `(delta * 50)` into `(delta * -50)`.

```js
(function() {
  function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= (delta * -50);
    document.body.scrollLeft -= (delta * -50);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
  } else {
    window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
  }
})();
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">

<div style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;" dir="ltr">

<p>月亮代表我的心</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>

</div>

</body>
```